# How to make css border like this?

Tags: css

I do this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mQip.jpg

I want to make border like below. Someone can help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP0Fd.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the orange background color on the li (list tag) with a 1px margin-bottom on parent UL tag add a background gradient that goes from left to right, orange to white to orange. i.e.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff670f 0%,#ffe3d3 49%,#ff670f 100%);
```

Heres my quick crude example http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/evdhb0ca/

Or even better use a Pseudo element for the gradient line separator as it looks like there's gradient on the sidebar itself i.e:

http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/pgc0ewub/

Comment: Don't forget to the click the stackoverflow check icon next to the correct answer